# Adding another variable to PayPal URL query string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal

I'm just learning.. can anyone please tell me how to add the variable p=1 when setting up this paypal parameter string please. Here is what it is like at the mo which works fine.. I just need to add p=1 but keep getting the syntax wrong I think. Thank you.

```
paypalParameterString.Append("return=http://examplesite.com/accounts.aspx?page=" & Request.QueryString("page") & "&")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add more parameters to the url you need to add an ampersand (&) between the parameters. For example

```
http://examplesite.com/accounts.aspx?parameter1=foo&parameter2=bar
```

So if you want to add parameter p with the value 1 to the url you mentioned above it should be like this

```
paypalParameterString.Append("return=http://examplesite.com/accounts.aspx?page=" & Request.QueryString("page") & "&p=1")
```

If you don't want to hardcode the value 1

```
paypalParameterString.Append("return=http://examplesite.com/accounts.aspx?page=" & Request.QueryString("page") & "&p=" & value)
```

Comment: Tried this but it returns from PayPal to simply http://www.examplesite.com/accounts.aspx?page=3

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [encode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx) your url since it's part of a parameter.

Put your url in a string variable

```
url = "http://examplesite.com/accounts.aspx?page=" & Request.QueryString("page") & "&p=1"
```

Then add it as a parameter by making sure to encode it

```
paypalParameterString.Append("return=" & Server.UrlEncode(url))
```

This will (for example) convert & to %26

*Note: You can put everything on one line if you want*

```
paypalParameterString.Append(Server.UrlEncode("return=http://examplesite.com/accounts.aspx?page=" & Request.QueryString("page") & "&p=1"))
```

Comment: Tried this but getting: Character is not valid error :-(

Comment: Do I deffo need to use "url" ? I changed it to "myurl" as I have "url" further down and it was causing problems ?

Comment: @Eggybread It's just an example variable, you can name it like you want or put the whole url directly in the UrlEncode

Comment: Tried it again like this..             paypalParameterString.Append("return=" & Server.UrlEncode("http://examplesite.com/accounts.aspx?page=" & Request.QueryString("page") & "&p=1"))

Still getting Character is not valid error 

Thank you for helping.